# knockout js grid swap input fields if data exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have an editable grid in which I populate with data after a user logs in with ajax.

I'm populating it with a device list and shipping information. Inside the device list json I have a Boolean "byod", if the selected row has the device with this data set to "0" I'd like to swap the "MAC Address" text field with the "Ship To" drop down.

fiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/QTUqD/15/, code is below:

```
<form id="extMngForm">

    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Extension</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Pin</th>
                <th>Device</th>
                <th>MAC Address</th>
                <th>Ship To</th>
                <th style="width: 100px; text-align:right;"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
       <tbody data-bind=" template:{name:templateToUse, foreach: pagedList }"></tbody>
    </table>

    <p class="pull-right addExt"><a class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: $root.add" href="#" title="edit"><i class="icon-plus"></i> Add Extension</a></p>

    <div class="pagination pull-left" data-bind='visible: pagedList().length > 0'>
        <ul><li data-bind="css: { disabled: pageIndex() === 0 }"><a href="#" data-bind="click: previousPage">Previous</a></li></ul>
        <ul data-bind="foreach: allPages">
            <li data-bind="css: { active: $data.pageNumber === ($root.pageIndex() + 1) }"><a href="#" data-bind="text: $data.pageNumber, click: function() { $root.moveToPage($data.pageNumber-1); }"></a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul><li data-bind="css: { disabled: pageIndex() === maxPageIndex() }"><a href="#" data-bind="click: nextPage">Next</a></li></ul>
    </div>

    <br clear="all" />
    <script id="extItems" type="text/html">
       <tr>
            <td style="width:20px;" data-bind="text: extension"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: email"></td>
            <td style="width:20px;" data-bind="text: vmpin"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: device.asObject && device.asObject() && device.asObject().name"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: macAddress"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: shipTo"></td>
            <td class="buttons">
                <a class="btn" data-bind="click: $root.edit" href="#" title="edit"><i class="icon-edit"></i></a>
                <a class="btn" data-bind="click: $root.remove" href="#" title="remove"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </script>

    <script id="editExts" type="text/html">
        <tr>
            <td style="width:20px;"><input style="width:65px;min-width: 65px;" data-errorposition="b" class="required" name="extension" data-bind="value: extension" /></td>
            <td><input data-errorposition="b" class="required" name="name" data-bind="value: name" /></td>
            <td><input data-errorposition="b" class="required" name="email" data-bind="value: email" /></td>
            <td style="width:20px;"><input style="width:65px;min-width: 65px;" data-errorposition="b" class="required" name="vmpin" data-bind="value: vmpin" /></td>
            <td>

            <select data-bind="options: $root.devicesForItem($data), optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id', value: device, valueAsObject: 'asObject'"></select>

            </td>
            <td><input name="macAddress" data-bind="value: macAddress" /></td>
            <td><select style="width:100px;" data-bind="options: $root.addressList, optionsText: 'locationName', optionsValue: 'locationName', value: shipTo"></select></td>
            <td class="buttons">
                <a class="btn btn-success" data-bind="click: $root.save" href="#" title="save"><i class="icon-ok"></i></a>
                <a class="btn" data-bind="click: $root.remove" href="#" title="remove"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </script>
</form>
```

---

```
window.ExtListViewModel = new function () {
    var self = this;
    window.viewModel = self;

    self.list = ko.observableArray();
    self.pageSize = ko.observable(10);
    self.pageIndex = ko.observable(0);
    self.selectedItem = ko.observable();
    self.extQty = ko.observable(20);

    self.devices = ko.observableArray([{"id":"gxp2100","name":"Grandstream GXP-2100","qty":"2","byod":"1"}, {"id":"gxp2100","name":"Grandstream GXP-2100 (BYOD)","qty":"1","byod":"0"}, {"id":"pcom331","name":"Polycom 331","qty":"2","byod":"0"}, {"id":"pcom331","name":"Polycom 331 (BYOD)","qty":"1","byod":"1"}]);
    self.addressList = ko.observableArray(['addressList']);
    self.availableDevices = ko.computed(function() {        
        var usedQuantities = {};
        self.list().forEach(function(item) {
            var device = item.device();
            if (device) {
                usedQuantities[device.id] = 1 + (usedQuantities[device.id] || 0);
            }
        });

        return self.devices().filter(function(device) {
            var usedQuantity = usedQuantities[device.id] || 0;
            return device.qty > usedQuantity;
        });
    });
    self.devicesForItem = function(item) {        
        var availableDevices = self.availableDevices();
        return self.devices().filter(function(device) {
            return device === item.device() || availableDevices.indexOf(device) !== -1;
        });
    }

    self.edit = function (item) {
            self.selectedItem(item);
    };

    self.cancel = function () {
        self.selectedItem(null);
    };

    self.add = function () {
            var newItem = new Extension();
            self.list.push(newItem);
            self.selectedItem(newItem);
            self.moveToPage(self.maxPageIndex());
    };
    self.remove = function (item) {

            if (confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this item?')) {

                    self.list.remove(item);
                    if (self.pageIndex() > self.maxPageIndex()) {
                        self.moveToPage(self.maxPageIndex());
                    }

            }
    };
    self.save = function () {
            self.selectedItem(null);
    };

    self.templateToUse = function (item) {
        return self.selectedItem() === item ? 'editExts' : 'extItems';
    };

    self.pagedList = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
        var size = self.pageSize();
        var start = self.pageIndex() * size;
        return self.list.slice(start, start + size);
    });
    self.maxPageIndex = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
        return Math.ceil(self.list().length / self.pageSize()) - 1;
    });
    self.previousPage = function () {
        if (self.pageIndex() > 0) {
            self.pageIndex(self.pageIndex() - 1);
        }
    };
    self.nextPage = function () {
        if (self.pageIndex() < self.maxPageIndex()) {
            self.pageIndex(self.pageIndex() + 1);
        }
    };
    self.allPages = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
        var pages = [];
        for (i = 0; i <= self.maxPageIndex() ; i++) {
            pages.push({ pageNumber: (i + 1) });
        }
        return pages;
    });
    self.moveToPage = function (index) {
        self.pageIndex(index);
    };


};

ko.applyBindings(ExtListViewModel, document.getElementById('extMngForm'));

function Extension(extension, name, email, vmpin, device, macAddress, shipTo){
    this.extension = ko.observable(extension);
    this.name = ko.observable(name);
    this.email = ko.observable(email);
    this.vmpin = ko.observable(vmpin);
    this.device = ko.observable(device);
    this.macAddress = ko.observable(macAddress);
    this.shipTo = ko.observable(shipTo);
};
ExtListViewModel.addressList = [{"shipping_address_street":"555 Lane","shipping_address_state":"TX","shipping_address_city":"Dallas","shipping_address_postalcode":"75000","locationName":"Preset"}, {"shipping_address_street":"555 Lane","shipping_address_state":"TX","shipping_address_city":"Dallas","shipping_address_postalcode":"75000","locationName":"Home"}];

//Shows device name not value (knockout extension)
ko.bindingHandlers.valueAsObject = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var value = allBindingsAccessor().value,
            prop = valueAccessor() || 'asObject';

        //add an "asObject" sub-observable to the observable bound against "value"
        if (ko.isObservable(value) && !value[prop]) {
              value[prop] = ko.observable();
        }
    },
    //whenever the value or options are updated, populated the "asObject" observable
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var prop = valueAccessor(),
            all = allBindingsAccessor(),
            options = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(all.options),
            value = all.value,
            key = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value),
            keyProp = all.optionsValue,
            //loop through the options, find a match based on the current "value"
            match = ko.utils.arrayFirst(options, function(option) {
               return option[keyProp] === key;
            });

        //set the "asObject" observable to our match
        value[prop](match);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, like I showed you in your other recent post, don't use `optionsValue` binding for your selects if you want the value to be the object itself (and then you don't need that valueAsObject stuff). So:

```
<select data-bind="options: $root.devicesForItem($data), optionsText: 'name', value: device"></select>
```

Second, your IDs need to be unique (not like in your current example) because your code depends on that.

Then, the rest is easy, you just need a simple computed boolean in your Extension objects that says whether the MAC address or the shipping thing is shown, e.g.:

```
this.showMac = ko.computed(function() {
        if (self.device())
            return self.device().byod !== '0';
        return true;
});
```

And use this computed in the bindings, e.g. `<!-- ko if: showMac -->` or `<td data-bind="text: showMac() ? macAddress : shipTo>"`

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/antishok/QTUqD/16/

Comment: Awesome man, thank you again. I'm having trouble wrapping my brain around the mvvm stuff. After seeing this though I don't know how I missed it. Oh and the valueAsObject was an attempt at sending different information to the database. I need the 'id' from the string sent instead of the selected 'name'. Any ideas?

Comment: are you sending the data to the DB via a regular form submit?

Comment: Then you can just grab the id's from your viewmodel, no? Instead of grabbing the value of the `<select>`, I mean

Comment: How would I do that though? This is what my submit ajax looks like: `$.ajax({
  url: '/activate/create',
  type: 'POST',
  data: ko.toJSON({
   ext: ExtListViewModel.list(),
   }),
  contentType: 'application/json'
 });`

Comment: Then that already sends the id of the selected device for each item.. what's the problem?

Comment: Man, you are right haha! My brain has been melting over this, I'm just overlooking tiny things haha. Thank you again man.